# SQLite, how to disable scientific notation

Tags: sqlite

I have a column of type real, when I do a query on that column (using SQLite3 command line interface) the data is shown in scientific notation, not much amusing particularly because the numbers after the exponent are sometimes truncated and not shown (weird!).
I've been trying to find a way to change 7.62939453125e-06 to its more friendly representation 0.00000762939453125 (I'd be happy with 7 decimal digits), to no avail. I'm using version 3.8.2, so printf is not an available choice. I even tried round(number*1000000)/1000000, same result.

Comment: Sqlite3 is a command line utility that enables you to access the SQLite libraries to perform queries on data in the SQLite storage format.  If the capabilities of sqlite3 don't match your needs, then perhaps you should use a different facility to interface with the SQLite libraries.  One of them may allow more output formatting options.

Comment: Thanks @scottb, but I think you'd agree that seeing the exponential part of a number someone decided to show you in scientific notation, is pretty much the need of everyone using the tool. I'd say that's more like a bug in the tool.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I have found to prevent scientific notation is to use the `printf` function:

```
sqlite> SELECT abs(1.0/1000000);
1.0e-06
sqlite> SELECT printf("%f", abs(1.0/1000000));
0.000001
```

Here's a link to the official docs:  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf